# PowerShell Reflection: Define a MIME type or subtype as a script's output type

Tags: powershell, reflection, documentation

It's possible in PowerShell to define an output type on scripts. Consider `myScript.ps1`:

```
[OutputType([String])]
param(
    [string]$name
)
```

The following returns `String`:

```
(Get-Command .\myScript.ps1).OutputType.Name
```

But I would like to specify that a script returns `text/json` or `text/xml`. What would be a good way of doing that?

Inventing types for OutputType (e.g. `[String.JSON]`) does not work.

Answer (score 6):

There are **two *independent, but complementary* mechanisms for declaring output types**:

**Important:** Both ways of declaring output types are *informative only* and *aren't enforced* by PowerShell at runtime (but the `[OutputType]` information is used for *tab-completion*).

- **Mechanism A**: Using the **[`[OutputType]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_outputtypeattribute) above the `param()` declaration** in a script or function, as in the question:

  - ***Always* use this mechanism, and, *if necessary*, *supplement* with mechanism B.**
  - Only recognizes **full type names** of .NET types or the name of PowerShell **type accelerators** and *no up-front validation* is performed, but if an unrecognized type is encountered *at invocation time*:

    - if originally specified as a *string* (e.g., `'System.Text.Encoding'`): it is *quietly ignored*.
    - if originally specified as a *type literal* (e.g., `[System.Text.Encoding]`): the function call *breaks on invocation*
  - This strict, type-based integration **enables tab completion / IntelliSense (command line / Visual Studio Code)**
  - As for **when you may want to use mechanism B *too***:

    - If the .NET type names don't tell the full story, as in the question.
    - If a function outputs multiple types and you want to verbally describe what types are output when.
- *[Supplemental]* **Mechanism B**: Using the **`.OUTPUTS` section of comment-based help**:

  - Accepts **free-form descriptions**; while referencing actual type names makes sense, doing so is not enforced.
  - While you *can* use this mechanism *alone*, doing so forgoes the advantages of tab completion and IntelliSense.
  - Therefore, **use it to *supplement* mechanism A, if needed**, but note that:

    - If both mechanisms are used, **`Get-Help` *only* shows the *mechanism B* definitions**.
    - Since the two mechanisms are independent, you **must *manually* ensure that the free-form information specified is *complete* and *consistent*** with the mechanism A declarations.

To **examine the output-type information with *human eyeballs*, use `(Get-Help <cmd>).returnvalues` (caveat: requires help to be defined, such as via comment-based help) or read the `OUTPUTS` section of the output from `Get-Help -Full <cmd>`**.
This will either show the free-form `.OUTPUTS` content or, in its absence, the full type names of the `[OutputType[]]`-declared types.
**For *programmatic access*, use `(Get-Command <cmd>).OutputType`**, which returns `[System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]` instances whose `.Type` property contains the actual type.

Details below, starting with the answer to the original question.

---

### Mechanism A: Using `OutputType` attribute(s) above `params()`:

You **may only specify *.NET types* as arguments to the `OutputType` attribute**, so strings such as `text/json` or `text/xml` that reflect *MIME types* won't work.

If you want *string* output, you've already chosen the closest approximation of your MIME types in terms of .NET types: `[OutputType([String])]`

You may specify multiple types in a single `[OutputType()]` attribute, or you may use individual attributes.
You *must* use individual attributes if you want to **map output types to specific parameter sets** (e.g., `[OutputType([string], ParameterSetName='NameOnly')]`).
As of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.0.1, however, this information is neither used by tab completion / IntelliSense nor reflected in the output from `Get-Help -Full`.

Note: **For a type to be recognized by the `OutputType` attribute** at invocation time,

- use either the ***full* type name** (e.g., `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]` rather than just `[Match]`) or the name of a PowerShell **type accelerator**, such as `[regex]`.

  - When in doubt, type `[<fullTypeName>]` at the prompt and see if it is recognized as a type; additionally **you may choose between specifying the type as a *string* (e.g., `'System.Text.Encoding'`) or as a *type literal* (e.g., (e.g., `[System.Text.Encoding]`), which has behavioral implications** - see below.
- **if the specified type isn't present *at invocation time***, e.g., because  the assembly containing the type hasn't been loaded, the behavior depends on how the output was declared:

  - if originally specified as a *string*: it is quietly ignored.
  - if originally specified as a *type literal*: the function call breaks on invocation

---

Beyond that,

- either: simply *describe* the specific types of strings that your cmdlet outputs in its help text, such as via mechanism B described below,
- or: create *custom .NET types* whose names reflect the desired conceptual type, and specify them in the `OutputType` attribute - see below.

As stated, despite its constrained nature, **the `OutputType` attribute is purely *informative at runtime*** - it is, however, **used for tab completion and IntelliSense (Visual Studio Code)**.

---

**Example of using a custom type:**

```
# Define an empty custom type for the sole purpose for being able to use
# it with the OutputType attribute.
# Note: On first call, this may take a second or two, as the code is being
#       compiled.
Add-Type @'
  namespace org.example {
   public class text_json {}
  }
'@

function foo {
  # Reference the custom type defined above; full type name required.
  [OutputType([org.example.text_json])]
  param(
      [string]$name
  )
}
```

You then get:

```
PS> (Get-Command foo).OutputType.Name
org.example.text_json
```

Note that the `[System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]` instances that `.OutputType` outputs are not the same as the `[type]` instances you get when you inspect a type directly:

The `.Name` property of `[System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]` corresponds to the `.FullName` property of `[type]`, so you get the *full* type name *if* the type is recognized (available in the session); otherwise, it is the name as originally specified.

---

### Mechanism B: Using the `.OUTPUTS` section in comment-based help:

Conceptual help topic [`Get-Help about_Comment_Based_Help`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847834.aspx) describes how section `.OUTPUTS` inside comment-based help for scripts and functions can be used to list *and describe* output types.

<sup>Note: Similarly, the `.INPUTS` section can be used to describe supported *input* types, though that is arguably less interesting, given that specifying input types is an integral part of parameter declaration and documentation. By and large, `.INPUTS` functions analogously to `.OUTPUTS`, with only differences mentioned below.</sup>

An `.OUTPUTS` section uses the following format suggested by the examples in the help topic, but note that the text is ultimately *free-form*, and no structure is *enforced*.

```
<type-name> <optional-description>
```

Even though the help topic (as of PSv5) doesn't mention it, it seems that in the event of multiple output types, each should be described in its *own* `.OUTPUTS` section.
That said, the free-form format allows you to describe multiple output-type descriptions in a *single* section.

Example, taking advantage of the free-form format to describe the output in terms of MIME types:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Does stuff.

.OUTPUTS
text/json. In case of x, returns a JSON [string].

.OUTPUTS
text/xml. In case of y, returns an XML [string].
#>
function foo {
  param()
}
```

Note that when using `Get-Help` to view the help as a whole, the (aggregated) `.OUTPUTS` (and `.INPUTS`) sections are only shown with `Get-Help -Full`.

Querying that information *programmatically* essentially yields the `OUTPUTS` section from
`Get-Help -Full` verbatim (with individual `.OUTPUTS` sections in the source concatenated with an empty line in between, and extra trailing empty lines):

```
PS> (Get-Help foo).returnvalues

text/json. In case of x, returns a JSON [string].

text/xml. In case of y, returns an XML [string].
```

To access the descriptions individually, by index:

```
PS> (Get-Help foo).returnvalues.returnvalue[0].type.name
text/json. In case of x, returns a JSON [string].
```

However, given the free-form nature of the descriptions and that they're intended for *human* consumption, this granular access may not be needed.

That said, using this form returns the text without extra whitespace, so `(Get-Help foo).returnvalues.returnvalue.type.name` can be used to return all text without empty lines.

This works analogously for the `.INPUTS` sections:
`(Get-Help foo).inputTypes.inputType.type.name`

Answer (score 1):

One neat way is using the PowerShell help comment syntax.

```
<# 
 .Synopsis
  Returns a list of files.

 .Description
  ...

 .Inputs
 text/csv

 .Outputs
 text/json[]

#>
```

You can access this information from the `Get-Help` object:

```
$cmd = Get-Help -Name .\components\FileList.ps1
"Input Type: " + $cmd.inputTypes.inputType[0].type.name
"Output Type: " + $cmd.returnValues.returnValue[0].type.name
```

Results in:

```
Input Type: text/csv
Output Type: text/json[]
```

Also works on standard cmdlets:

```
(Get-Help Get-Date).returnValues[0].returnValue[0].type.name
```

Returns:

```
System.DateTime or System.String
```

Comment: That's an interesting alternative that essentially allows free-form output- (and input-)type descriptions, leaving you free to use MIME types to describe the output.
Given the free-form nature and that the information is intended for human consumption rather than machine parsing, you can access the information in aggregated
form more simply as just `.returnvalues` and `.inputTypes`; e.g.: `(Get-Help Get-Date).returnValues` and `(Get-Help Get-Date).inputTypes`