# Undefined property name appears valid

Tags: powershell

The following two commands produce different output.

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property Length
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property Len
```

`Len` is not a member of `System.IO.FileInfo`. Is PowerShell matching `Len` to the `Length` member? If not, then why is there no error message saying that `Len` is not a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not member of `System.IO.FileInfo` as you can see by adding the `-Debug`switch:

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property Len -Debug
```

Output looks like:

```
DEBUG: "Sort-Object" - "Len" cannot be found in "InputObject".
```

I guess the reason for that is the defensive implementation of the [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object):

> If an object does not have one of the specified properties, the
>   property value for that object is interpreted by the cmdlet as Null
>   and is placed at the end of the sort order.

Comment: Having that undefined property assumed to be `$null` and moved to the end does not produce the same result as not specifying any property. Using `Sort-Object` with no properties appears to not change the order.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49201672/45375) with **more general information**:

While **PowerShell's *elastic syntax* only applies to parameter *names***  (e.g., specifying just `-p` for `-Property`) , not *values* (arguments), you *do* have **options for completing *values***:

- At *edit* time: **use *tab completion***:

  - This works on the command line as well as in Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell extension installed (where you'll get **IntelliSense** as well), **as long as PowerShell can statically infer the output type(s)**<sup>[1]</sup>
    of the command in the previous pipeline segment.
- At *runtime*:
  **`Sort-Object` and several other cmdlets allow you to use a *wildcard expression* to match property names**:

  ```
  Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property Len* # "Len*" matches "Length"
  ```

Note that *multiple* properties may match, and that *a given parameter must be explicitly designed to support wildcards* (unlike in POSIX-like shells, it is *not* PowerShell itself that resolves the wildcards).

---

When **accessing a nonexistent property on an object *directly***, no error is reported by default, and `$null` is returned:

```
(Get-Item /).Foo  # Outputs $null as the value of nonexistent property "Foo"
```

By contrast, if `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is in effect, a (statement-terminating) error is reported in that case, but note that **`Set-StrictMode` does *not* apply when passing property names as *arguments***, such as to `Sort-Object` above.

---

As for **a possible motivation for why `Sort-Object` doesn't enforce the existence of specified properties**:

PowerShell allows you to pass objects that are *any mix of types* as input through the pipeline, with the objects getting passed *one at a time*.
(Similarly, PowerShell's default array type is `[object[]]`, which allows you to create mixed-type arrays such as `1, 'hi', $True`)

Even with (potentially) homogeneous input (such as the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances emitted by `Get-ChildItem -File`, for instance), a receiving command cannot detect that case *up front*, because it only ever sees one object at a time.

In general, cmdlets should be able to handle a mix of types among the input gracefully, and treating nonexistent properties as `$null` is overall the better choice, especially given that:

- a cmdlet may still be able to act meaningfully on the input if at least a *subset* of the input objects have the property of interest (see below).
- a cmdlet cannot know *in advance* whether that subset is empty.

**Example with heterogeneous input:**

Send an array of custom objects through the pipeline and sort it by property `val`, which one of the objects lacks:

```
[pscustomobject] @{ n = 'o1'; val = 2 },
[pscustomobject] @{ n = 'o2' },
[pscustomobject] @{ n = 'o3'; val = 1 } | Sort-Object val
```

Output:

```
n  val
-  ---
o3   1
o1   2
o2
```

Sorting was performed among all the input objects that do have a `.val` property, whereas those that don't were placed at the *end*, as stated in the quote from `Sort-Object`'s documentation in Martin's answer.

---

<sup>[1] This should be true of all built-in cmdlets; to ensure that it works with custom functions, define them with `[OutputType(<type>)]` attributes - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40570149/45375) of mine for more.</sup>